# Refactor multidimensional array function to ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

Currently putting together a function in my app and was wondering if theres a neater way to write this with ES6 rather than use two for loops.

The aim is create a multi-dimensional array to track co-ordinates x & y. This works fine as it stands but I'm hoping to make it neater.

```
function setBoard() {
boardParts = new Array(tileCount);
for (let i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    boardParts[i] = new Array(tileCount);
    for (let j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
        boardParts[i][j] = new Object();
        boardParts[i][j].x = tileCount - 1 - i;
        boardParts[i][j].y = tileCount - 1 - j;
    }
}
emptyLoc.x = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].x;
emptyLoc.y = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].y;
solved = false;
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: There are object literals even in ES5 :-)

Comment: Also, `emptyLoc.x = emptyLoc.y = 0;` - those are always the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go ES6, you can use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from) to generate the arrays:

```js
const tileCount = 4;

const boardParts = Array.from({ length: tileCount }, (_, i) => 
  Array.from({ length: tileCount }, (_, j) => ({
    x: tileCount - 1 - i,
    y: tileCount - 1 - j
  }))
);

console.log(boardParts);
```

Comment: Okay, fair enough, there **is** something in ES2015 that relates to this. I wouldn't say it's an improvement necessarily, but the OP did specifically ask... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Array#from is the closest JS gets to python's list comprehensions, and it's a pity that the [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) are not supported in JS yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly in ES2015+ that helps with that (well, other than `Array.from` [as Ori Drori points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306942/157247), which you may or may not want), but there are several things you can do to improve it that were also available in ES5, see comments:

```
function setBoard() {
    boardParts = []; // No need to create with initial `length`, generic arrays
                     // aren't really arrays, no pre-allocation necessary
    for (let i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
        boardParts[i] = []; // See above
        for (let j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
            boardParts[i][j] = {           // Object initializer rather than
                x: tileCount - 1 - i,      // `new Object` and then prop
                y: tileCount - 1 - j       // assignment
            };
        }
    }
    emptyLoc.x = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].x;
    emptyLoc.y = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].y;
    solved = false;
}
```

Separately to the above: The function presented expects to find `boardParts`, `tileCount`, `emptyLoc`, and `solved` declared in a containing context. Normally it's not ideal to have functions that purely work through side-effects unless they're object initializers of some kind...